# TypeError (expected Hash (got String) for param `content'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to add widgEditor to a form in ruby on rails however whenever I hit submit I get the following error:

```
TypeError (expected Hash (got String) for param `content'
```

The form code is as follows:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= f.text_area :content,  :cols => "20", :rows=>"4", :class=>"widgEditor" %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
```

has anyone got any experience with this issue?

Comment: can you see what is being posted with firebug or chrome developerbar?

Comment: Sorry! Here it is: 
template_contentWidgToolbarSelectBlock:
template%5Bcontent%5D:<p>I've </p><b>entered</b><p> some content here</p>
template%5Bcontent%5DWidgEditor:true

Comment: Can you past the complete form code.

Comment: Manuel set me off on the right direction , it was submitting too many parameters from what I can tell. By adding $(this.theExtraInput).remove(); to the cleanSource function of widgEditor it now only submits the content field and works fine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was submitting too many parameters from what I can tell. By adding $(this.theExtraInput).remove(); to the cleanSource function of widgEditor it now only submits the content field and works fine.

Answer (score 23):

for others who met the same problem:

this error is caused when you have two fields in your form like:

```
video: 'some string'
video['url']:  'some url'
```

then rails will crash with the error: expected Hash (got String) for param

the solution is quite simple: change 'video' to something else. e.g.:

```
video_origin_url: 'some string'
video['url']: 'some url'
```

see this question also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19246703/445908

Comment: Dude you have no idea how much this helped me.  It's just not an error that's worded obviously at all.  Very lost until I saw your comment!

Comment: Ditto to @notaceo. The default error message should be replaced with your explanation. :) Thanks!

Comment: A+ just wanted to also say thanks a ton. In my case I had forgotten I put a hidden field in the top of the form that I was updating with JS.